# How to code a htacess file for multiple languages?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am writing code for a website where it will choose which language to load:

```
if(isset($_GET['language']) && $_GET['language']=='jp') include(lozalize/jp.php);
else include(lozalize/en.php);
```

However, I would like to have a nice url:

```
www.site.com/en/
www.site.com/en/contact
www.site.com/en/projects/project1
```

Where contact, projects and project1 are folders with their own index.php.

How can I write an .htaccess file (If this is even the answer!) to not have links like:

www.site.com/contact/?language=en

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? Please show us you've done some research on the topic.

Comment: I have tried getting the current URL and parsing out the segments:$segments = explode('/', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);. However, $segment[0] = index.php when I use the URL 'www.site.com/en/. I also tried some .htaccess files to rewrite the URL but I am getting nothing.

Comment: I also tried using: $segments = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); which gives me the language code. But when I try www.site.com/en/contact it says page not found. Any thoughts?

Comment: You're heading the wrong way. Take a look at [URL Rewriting](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html).

Comment: [Here's a tutorial for beginners](http://www.addedbytes.com/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/).

Comment: After looking at that guide I cant get '/en/contact working' but i did get the basic 'en/' 'kr/'. RewriteRule    ^en/?$    index.php?language=en    [NC,L]
    RewriteRule    ^kr/?$    index.php?language=kr    [NC,L]

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(en|jp)/(.*)$ /$2?language=$1 [QSA,L]
```